# Does 3rd party go library need to be recompiled when I use them?

Tags: go

I am a starter to use `go`. I found people publish go library just by pushing to github repo with a tag. It doesn't really compile anything when publishing. There is not any build artefact except source code.

When I use a 3rd party library, a command `go get xxx` is called to run. Will the library be compiled in my local along with my source code together? So go doesn't have any compiled library?

Comment: yes the mainline dev flow is decentralized publishing, download dependencies code to compile with. https://go.dev/doc/modules/developing

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Does 3rd party go library need to be recompiled when I use them?

Yes.

> Will the library be compiled in my local along with my source code together?

Yes.

> So go doesn't have any compiled library?

Basically no.

Comment: Does it mean I have to open source go library? Is there a way to publish a go library without open the source code?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Publishing the source code and Open Source are different things. If you want to distribute a Go library you have to distribute the source code.

Comment: If I want to publish a go library but the source code is confidential, is there a way to publish it?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao „confidential“ often is an euphemism for either „just crap“ or „fishy to illegal“. To answer your question: No.